# Aws data glue crawler-table not found

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, aws-glue-data-catalog

I am running my crawler and in logs it shows me that a table has be created and added to the database which also has been created. However when I want to check the table it's not there. I found some problems where people couldn't create a table because of lacking permissions, but that shouldn't be the mistake in my case.  It also shows in the crawler under table added. Value jumps from 0 to 1 but I can't find the table anywhere.
Maybe someone had a similar problem  ?

[image]

below you can see the logs which show that it should be added

[image]

but if i go to the tables section it shows two tables  which i createdd before with another crawler. i set the new one p as the two before still this time i'm not getting any table
[image]

UPDATE:

Can it be a UI bug ? when I'm running get tables in CLI i can see the table. Since I'm not very familiar with working with CLI I wanted to finish it over der UI? Is there anthing I can do to unbug the UI

Comment: Could you share the Crawler Configuration please?

Comment: Yes I'll share it in 2 hours when I'm home

Comment: @RobertKossendey uploaded

Comment: Are you in the correct region on the console (UI)?

Comment: yes, as written before i can find the table now when i'm setting up the crawler and even in athena, but i can not find i in the tables section to e.g. edit the partition